# Select text till and including pattern

Tags: search, regular-expression, visual-mode

I want to select text from multiple lines up till and including the pattern *pattern*. When I use `v/pattern` the text till *attern* is selected (not including attern). How can I select text including *attern*?

E.g., when I have the text

> yada yada
>   yada n pattern

and my cursor is at the first y, I am looking for a command to highlight everything.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just append `/e`

to your search pattern.

> v/pattern/e